# Сортировка строк таблицы по цвету строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток. Появилась необходимость сортировки таблицы по цвету **background-color** строки. Решил создать объект colorMap и поместить туда строки таблицы, где key это **background-color** строки, а уже потом состряпать итоговую табличку из этого объекта (может не совсем верно).

```
var $tr = $(".norms tbody tr");

var colorMap = {};
$tr.each(function () {
    var bckColor = $(this).css('background-color');

    if (colorMap[bckColor] == undefined) {
        colorMap[bckColor] = $(this);
    } else {
        colorMap[bckColor] = colorMap[bckColor].push($(this));
    }
});
```

И вот тут я где-то туплю, потому как ругается на **push is not function** со всем вытекающим. Объект должен быть вида obj = { color1:[строка1, строка3...], color2:[строка4, строка6...] }. Подскажите, дайте совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить

```
if (colorMap[bckColor] == undefined) {
    colorMap[bckColor] = $(this);
} else {
    colorMap[bckColor] = colorMap[bckColor].push($(this));
}
```

на

```
 (colorMap[bckColor] || (colorMap[bckColor] = [])).push($(this))
```

Comment: спасибо выручил, только я не понял что и как)

Comment: Ошибка возникала потому, что по ключу `colorMap[bckColor]` содержимое не соотвествовало ожидаемому типу (массив), а массива там не было из-за того, что автор кода не успел прочитать что такое массив, что возвращает вызов `.push` и другие базовые вещи

Comment: вот же какой некомпетентный автор..